# how to remove a bright outline at the edge of LRC segmentation mask?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

I have reduced exposure on an inverted "sky" mask attempting to create a high-contrast horizon against the distant hills in this photo but how do I remove the bright line across the first ridgeline?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit the mask directly with a hard(er) edged brush. But you would probably be better doing this in PS where there are more masking tools/options.